# Sending json post request with python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

With the firefox plugin "HttpFox" i'm getting the POST request which looks like this:

```
{'json':'{"command":"SEARCH","data":{"someData":"someValue","otherData":"otherData"}}'}
```

Now i need to send a http request build with python to get the same data as i would get via browser. See code:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
payload = ?
req = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
```

My problem is:
I'm not sure how to build the payload. It should be a dictionary as well, but im confused because of the POST type which is delivered with HttpFox. There are two dictionaries inside the main dictionary.

How should i handle this ? 
Appreciate any help.

Comment: The outer `'json'` key is probably *not* part of the JSON payload. It is not valid JSON, for example, since it is using single quotes. Are you certain it is not just the value shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution:

It was necessary to build a dict like this:

```
valueString = """{"command":"SEARCH","data":{"someData":"someValue","otherData":"otherData"}}"""
/// the """ ensures that the whole text between """ is handled as a string.

payload = {'json': valueString}
```

The key 'json' requieres a string. In this case the string looks like a dictionary.

That's it.

Comment: You now created a nested *string* in your JSON payload, not nested objects.

Comment: you could also have defined `values = {"command":"SEARCH","data":{"someData":"someValue","otherData":"otherData"}}` and `payload = {'json': json.dumps(values)`